# Where's the question about monitoring IoT devices from a plane?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Has the question about monitoring IoT devices on plane been auto-deleted? Here is the [**link to the original post**](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/201/could-iot-devices-be-monitored-real-time-while-on-a-plane).

I assume this post was removed because [the system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/338924)

So I know the user got deleted, I don't know it's score, but it was closed so guess it might have been negative and I guess that took the question down the drain.

I think it wasn't to bad an edge question to test our scope with. Can we get it back? Maybe have Community own it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the question *was* originally removed because of the down-votes when the user requested their account be deleted. The handling of that question was unfortunate; I restored the post.

> Unnecessary snarkiness in the comments. This is not a welcoming site.

The user is right. For a consumer-level question, how is this *NOT* a legitimate inquiry? It takes a certain level of technical snobbery to assume that how networks work or how these devices work is just an *innate* knowledge everyone is born with.

That aside, let's be mindful that it is really easy for a community to become insular and unwelcoming when a well-meaning question is treated like it's beneath them to ask. The user was embarrassed for having dare asked such a "retarded question." So they left.

Let's not do that.

It is helpful to remind ourselves on occasion to keep things friendly and constructive and to **be tolerant of others** who may not know everything you know. That's just good advice in general.

Comment: While we all agree to *be nice* and to be tolerant of others it seems a little far fetched to call the whole community unwelcoming. In this particular situation at least three users that I am aware of tried to reach out to the now deleted user and resolve the issue in chat - to no avail. It is also hard to community moderate something when you cannot track the issue down properly, e.g. when parts of the comments are deleted or changed (obviously this is when mod powers come in handy). However, I take it from the last days in chat)that virtually all of the new community set out to be welcoming.

Comment: @Ghanima The quote is of course one user's experience. It would be silly to suggest it is 100% inclusive of everyone on the site, but there's something to be taken away from the anecdote nonetheless.

Comment: Either way, you're right about pointing this young community in the right direction now (*The beginning is a very delicate time.*). We shall try harder to be welcoming and inclusive.

Comment: There can never be enough reminders for the *be nice policy.*